# "engineer of" or "Engineer in"

Tags: expressions, prepositions

What is the correct expression when we want to say :`The Grade of someone is`:

> Engineer of Applied Sciences & Information Technology.

or

> Engineer in Applied Sciences & Information Technology.

Comment: Typically it'd be: "Applied Sciences & Information Technology Engineer"

Comment: When in doubt, place it in apposition, as above @Jim or: *Engineer **,** Applied Sciences & Information Technology.*

Comment: @Hugh- good point.

Comment: I have a degree of "Master of Engineering with specialization in Electrical Engineering".  At one time the title given me by my employer was "Senior Associate Engineer".  There is no single rule that covers all the bases.

Comment: I'd say "Master of Engineering" in "Electrical Engineering" rather than use 'of'. So my answer to the OP would be that the second form using 'in' is correct, but I can't present any grammatical rules to back up my position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use both variants. I'd also take into account both comments to your question - those two ways are fairly good to use.
Although for the formal Degree one should use an expression from that Degree document (diploma) - like "Master of Engineering in Applied Sciences & Information Technology". Usually, degrees expressed like Master/Bachelor of Something in Something. But the best way is to quote directly from the Diploma. If it's from some other country, one should ask for the translation in his alma mater. They decide :)

Comment: I'm not sure about both variants being equally good, but +1 for Master/Bachelor of Something in Something, i.e. "degree name" in "subject". I think the OP is looking for "title" in "specialty", so "Engineer" in "(the field of) digital electronics" which would make "Engineer" in "digital electronics" the way to go